# Handling 20K files of 500M each

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, filesystem, raid, performance

I have 20K files. The size varies from 150M to 500M each. My files are tend to grow with time up to 500M.

My usage scenario ETL (all happens within 8 minutes):

1. Read file
2. Modify it in memory
3. Write file back

My usage rate is: 10 ETL per minute.

> ETL - Extract, Transform, Load - in my case it is (Read, Modify, Write)

I want to handle all this data with two 10 TB HDD in a RAID1 mode.

I use Ubuntu 18.04. For server I will use consumer hardware, not server grade stuff.

So, it there is any good linux file system that can chunk my entire HDD to 500M sections where I can keep my files? I want to avoid fragmentation hell, so my idea is to have dedicated 500M sections or so. I am OK to sacrifice space for speed and performance.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that you are trying to optimize a problem that don't exists. Just use any of the normal Linux filesystems, Both ext4 and xfs supports 16 TB partitions or more.

Comment: 500M isn't particularly big. Why do you think there will be an issue here?

Comment: With small partitions, you will achieve what you want to avoid: fragmentation.

Comment: I want to have one partition per one file. If I delete everything from the partition every time I need to update file - there will be no fragmentation.